# Azure Service Fabric Endpoint vs Port

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

This screenshot was taken while creating a Service Fabric Cluster. 
Apparently, all these marked fields are for adding ports. But some are called `endpoints` and some `port`. What's the difference?

[image: Node type configuration endpoints and ports]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand in *this context* as:

**endpoint** a port that is available from outside your cluster.

**Port** just a port open in the node without actually being exposed externally.

Reverse Proxy is considered a port because it is not public available by default, you have to open it, becoming an endpoint.